# How to make arrow function async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following code that checks the existance of a file and if present, parses the JSON data from it:

```
fs.access(dbPath, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        else{
            console.log('Database found. Processing data.');
            dbObj = processDatabaseFile(dbPath);
            console.log('checkonstartup: '+dbObj);
            return;
        }
    });
```

And here is the processDatabaseFile:

```
function processDatabaseFile(path){
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) =>{
        if (err) throw err;
        let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        return jsonData;
    })
}
```

My problem is when the fs.access function is being called, it returns sooner than the `processDatabaseFile(dbPath)` returns.
Eg. I want to make it use async await, but I don't know how to do that.

Tried putting `async (err) => { ...` declaration and then using
`dbObj = await processDatabaseFile(dbPath)` but it gives errors around the if-else and semicolons and missing brackets.

Feedback is appreciated.

EDIT:
About the errors regarding adding async-await. I was using VSCode and it turns out ESLint and JSHint conflicts each other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make fat arrow function async using the syntax below.

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
    const result = await someAsyncFunc();
}
```

Comment: Does someAsyncFunc() in `await someAsyncFunc()` have to be really async?

Comment: @VikingPingvin Yes, it must return a promise

Comment: No, `await`ed value can be just a value, `await 2 + 2` will amount to `4`. But if `someAsyncFunc()` is callback-based and doesn't return anything, then `await someAsyncFunc()` will be just undefined. You need to promisify it first.

Comment: Oh yeah it expects a Promise to be returned from `someAsyncFunc()`.  But, if `someAsyncFunc()` is not asynchronous I think there is no point in using `await`.

Comment: In my case it is, since it uses fs.readFile(), and I don't really want to make it blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Promisify fs.readFile(), in Node you get `promisify` out of the box. Something like

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

fs.access(dbPath, async (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    else {
        console.log('Database found. Processing data.');
        const dbObj = await processDatabaseFile(dbPath);
        console.log('checkonstartup: ' + dbObj);
    }
});

async function processDatabaseFile(path) {
    const data = await readFileAsync(path);
    return JSON.parse(data);
})
```